# I wan to make a cross line in Matrix diagonal from 2nd diagonal matrix from right to left

Tags: c#

I made Matrix diagonal with dimensional array and two loops
and I have two crosa one by changing the color line from right to the left button how can I do this ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPUDz.png)

this is my code I made the cross line from the left to right button
and now I want from Right to Left button
and this is my code

```
static void DisplayMatrixWithCross(int[,] matrix)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < 7; row++)
            {
                for (int column = 0; column < 7; column++)
                {
                    if (row == column)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.Write(matrix[row, column] + " ");
                    }

                    else if ()
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                        Console.Write(matrix[row, column] + " ");
                    }
                    else {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                        Console.Write(matrix[row, column] + " ");
                    }

                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }

        }
```

I added a photo  hope you can see it !

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem here. Try to use the methods .GetLength(0) and .GetLength(1).
You need only two IF statements.
Let me show you my code, so far that's all I've got:

```
static void DisplayMatrixWithCross(int[,] matrix)
{

    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.GetLength(0); row++)
    {


        for (int col = 0; col < matrix.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            if (row == (col - 5) + 5)
            {

                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

            }

            Console.ResetColor();

            if (row == (col + 5) - 5) 
            {

                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;

            }


            Console.Write("{0,3} ", matrix[row, col].ToString("00"));

        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```